# Want to dive deep in "functions"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, function-and-relation-composition

I want to learn "functions" specifically these topics--

```
   Functions- one-one, many-one, into, onto

   Increasing or decreasing Functions

   Inverse Functions

   Invertible Functions

   Even and Odd Functions

 Explicit and Implicit Functions

 Periodic Functions

 Bounded and unbounded Functions

 Constant and Identity Functions

 Absolute Value Function

 Signum Function

 Polynomial and Rational Function

 Linear Function

 Exponential Function

 Logarithmic Function

 Greatest Integer Function

 Graphical representation of a Function

 Algebraic operations on Functions

 Composite Functions

 Basic Transformations on Graphs
```

I searched several books on calculus (Spivak,Apostol) or pre-calculus but they just focus very basic on functions, so please tell me is there any book which can satisfy my need?

Comment: Spivak covers most of this very well.

Comment: Try googling "nelson advanced functions 12 pdf download"

Comment: Thanks Bro! you actually answered in the comment better than the only answer in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the topics you mention are standard material in a precalculus course. Any text will cover them. You can look on line for one that matches the way you like to learn things.

You probably won't find a book that's explicitly about "functions" - the reason to study them at your level is because you need them for calculus, which is why they are in a precalculus course. Some calculus books (like Spivak) review this material, but Spivak is pretty abstract.

Comment: So, is there any book on precalculus/calculus that you recommend?

Comment: @TanishqJaiswal I've no particular recommendation. That's why I suggested you browse on line. Good luck.